# Value in Dynamic Generated PHP Dropdown doesn't change

Tags: javascript, php

So i have made dropdown menu which is dynamic generated by my mysql db.
It is displaying all kinds of names and thats right.

So i now want to get the value of the selected entry (in my case the name)
Todo so i have made a send button with a function that triggers on a click event.
BUT here comes the hard thing for me: It doesn't matter how or to what i change the dropdown, (even if it is displayed correctly in the field) but on the backend i always get the same value/name.

Here's my index.php

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <select  id=selected_project name="selected_project">
        <?php
        include 'get_data.php';
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            echo "<option value=$row[ID]>$row[Name]</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
    <button onclick="sendForm()">Send</button>
    <!--<canvas id="yearly_chart"></canvas>-->

<script>
    let dropdownMenu = document.getElementById('selected_project');
    let ddValue = dropdownMenu.options[dropdownMenu.selectedIndex].text;

    function sendForm() {
        console.log(ddValue);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Problem once again is, that the output of console.log ddValue in the SendForm Function is always the same.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You're setting the value of `ddValue` at the start of the script. It's just a primitive value, it's not linked to the value of the drop-down. Read the value from the element in the function to get the current selected value.

Comment: Ah Thank you, that did ist for me 